# How to handle failed methods: by using exceptions or making the methods return bool?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to handle failed methods:

1. using exceptions
2. making the methods return bool

The first approach is when something goes wrong to throw an exception.
But the problematic code needs to be placed in a try block,
and then you need to write the catch block.

The second approach you need to check the return value from
the method, and then do something.

So basically isn't it the same mechanism? You have two parts:
detecting that something goes wrong and then doing something about it.
So does it matter then which approach I use?

Comment: Not really the same mechanism. The first part can actually tell you the exact problem so that you can investigate it. Returning a bool only tells you that it was successful or not, doesn't tell you anything else.

Comment: http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/exceptions.html

Comment: @AliAlamiri that is obviously a moot point because you can return an `int`.

Comment: @Andrey what would returning an int tell you about the problem?

Comment: If it can be handled locally, then it's the same mechanism - the caller detects and handles the failure. If it can't, then the caller can simply ignore an exception, but must pass a return code up to its caller - which is more error prone.

Comment: You could obviously return any type of object, including the exception object you would otherwise throw. (Unless C++ has some quirk I'm unaware of.) So it's really about the mechanism, not about the actual data.

Comment: @MEMark: There's only a single return type, while you can throw (just about) any type. You'll need quite a lot of messing around with polymorphism to get the flexibility of exceptions from a return value.

Comment: I'm surprised this question was put on hold, since most answers look far from opinion-based, but are instead supported by objective arguments. Voting to reopen.

Comment: There is also a third option in the form of `std::error_code` which is kind of halfway between the two options. Lots more info besides bool, soft equivalency but also ignorable (which could be good or bad depending on the circumstances).

Comment: @MikeSeymour, that is true. But being able to throw any object would equal a return type of `void *`, right? It just means you loose any type constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main benefit with exceptions is that they are non-local. You can catch an exception several invocation layers away from where it was thrown. That way, code in between doesn't have to care about exceptions (except ensuring proper cleanup during unwinding, i.e. being exception safe), which makes it less likely that an exceptional situation gets forgotten. But this benefit comes at a price: stack unwinding is more complicated than simply returning a value. In terms of performance, the return value approach is usually simpler.

So I'd use these to choose: if for some reason the only reasonable place to deal with a problem is directly at the location where the function was called, and if you are fairly certain that every caller will include some kind of error handling code in any case, and is not likely to forget doing so, then a return value would be best. Otherwise, I'd go for an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can reach the same behavior with both approaches, but Exception can give 2 added values:

1) You don't have to handle the error in the exact calling method, it can be anywhere up the call stack. this remove the `if(!doSomthing()) return false;` from the code when you just want to pass the error up.

2) It allow you to write a block of code, under one `try` and handle all the errors under it in one `catch` block.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple answer. For instance, here is the conclusion of the article [C++ Exceptions: Pros and Cons](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38449/C-Exceptions-Pros-and-Cons)

> There is no simple answer to the "exceptions or error codes" question. The decision needs to be made based on a specific situation that a development team faces. Some rough guidelines may be:
>
> If you have a good development process and code standards that are actually being followed, if you are writing modern-style C++ code that relies on RAII to clean up resources for you, if your code base is modular, using exceptions may be a good idea.
>
> If you are working with code that was not written with exception safety in mind, if you feel there is a lack of discipline in your development team, or if you are developing hard real-time systems, you should probably not use exceptions.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with that “lack of discipline” argument: those who lack discipline in terms of exception safety will likely also forget checking error return values.

Answer (score 3):

My personal rule is to raise exception only when something exceptional occurs, ie when the problem may not have appeared at all. Otherwise I use return value (most of the time).

For example, when searching for a file that *MUST* exists, not finding it raises an exception. But if the file may or may not exists, not finding it is not exceptional so no need for an exception.

Answer (score 3):

There's no answer for all situations. Both approaches have strengths and weaknesses:

Exceptions:

- are slightly more verbose to handle locally
- can simply be ignored if the error can't be handled locally
- can carry as much information as you like about the error, both statically (in the exception type) and dynamically (in the thrown object)
- require a handler somewhere to avoid terminating the program
- may have more runtime overhead (but may have less when nothing is thrown, depending on how they're implemented)
- require the code to be exception safe

Return values:

- must be manually passed up the stack if not handled locally: prone to bugs if you forget
- have a fixed type, limiting how much information they can carry (although you could return a pointer to a polymorphic type, and deal with the associated lifetime management issues)
- are awkward to use if the function also needs to return something on success

Comment: *have a fixed type, limiting how much information they can carry* => that would be an implementation detail, you could return a polymorphic value.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: True, you could return a pointer to something, with a certain amount of faff to manage the object it points to. I've added a note to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main differences: (a) it is easier for the calling code to just silently ignore the boolean status code. (b) Exceptions provide more context than mere `false`. You can distinguish business-logic errors from I/O errors from input validation errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer bools. I'd say its personal preference. 
I have found it easier to read.

Comment: As you can see from the other answers, there are actual arguments to think about. So it does not boil down to personal preference

Comment: Ok, arguments. Bools are a simpler concept. If you use a return, it is part of the function, and you can pick and choose whether to handle exceptions at the time. People are suggesting that a return provides no info, well you can choose whether to provide info i.e. if( return == false) { print "error message" }. It is also kinda handy for debugging to have everything all in the same scope, having the check directly after the return. Catching in another layer like @MvG says sounds overcomplex.

Comment: A lot of points have been made already in the answers on this page. Your version works well for simple cases. When printing the error message and signaling *failure* to the call site is not enough, exceptions become a very nice feature

Comment: So you chose bool as a return, now 10 iterations later you decide that you have a new return situation. Bool is no longer enough. You have to change the signature. Now you have to change all call sites to handle the new signature. With exceptions this is handled easier.

Comment: Well... not necessarily bool. You could return an int if you fancied, allowing you to have any number of error values. I do see situations for exceptions, however.